# How to change tif file crs

Tags: python, coordinate-transformation, epsg

Hi I am wondering how to change the tif file crs as I want to overlay one my shapefiles (called imd) onto the tif file, if I do not change the coordinate, they can not be merged.

Here is the code:

```
import rasterio
src = rasterio.open('M:/lab3/man22.tif')
left, bottom, right, top = src.bounds
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6, 6))
ax.imshow(src.read(1), cmap='gray', extent=(left, right, bottom, top))
imd.plot(column='imd_score', cmap='Purples', 
         linewidth=0.1, alpha=0.75,ax=ax)
```

The man22.tif file's CRS is: epsg=3857, and the imd.shp is 27700. Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Have you tried `rasterio.warp.reproject` ?
 https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/reproject.html